# Ubuntu won't boot after successful installation (Black screen appears and nothing happens)

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (dual boot win 8) via live usb created using pendrive linux. I have a sony vaio multi-touch screen with nvidia geforce CUDA. You can check the specifications here : http://www.sony.co.uk/product/vaio-j-series/vpcj11m1e-b

After successful installation, it shows the boot menu (purple screen) and upon selecting ubuntu, it shows a black screen and nothing happens.

I tried the recovery mode and chose failsafeX option, the next screen said that "you are running on low graphics" and wont go any further.

I upgraded grub using root option and the very same problem persists.

i tried the very same version of ubuntu without installing and the behaviour wont change.

Do i have to find another iso file that would support the hardware of my system or is there a fix available?

Kindly help me out....i am really struggling with this OS but i want to make it work

Thanks

Comment: Did you use the 64-bit version? 12.04.2 LTS? A brief installation procedure is given in this question. See if you did it differently. http://askubuntu.com/questions/319179/partition-in-my-laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling your nvidia drivers:

- When the low graphics mode window appears, press `ctrl`+`alt`+`f1`
- login with your username and password
- use `sudo apt-get purge nvidia` to remove all nvidia drivers
- reinstall the proper drivers using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
- reboot you machine using `sudo reboot`

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Choose second line option in grub menu to enter recovery mode, then again there will a menu with host of options out of which choose the re-boot in normal option or the similar and now it starts off successfully ... this solution is applicable for dual boot of windows vista business with ubuntu 12.04 ... HTH