# Partition in my laptop

Tags: partitioning, windows

Is it possible to make a partition in my laptop and run Ubuntu and Windows 8 side by side. and if it is then what should i do to make a partition in my laptop

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Windows 8 installed first. You need to create some unalocated space.This allocated space will be used for Ubuntu to be installed on. You can use this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zT1aNe38T9Y) that shows you how to make an unalocated space in windows 8.
Now you just have to install Ubuntu normal and it will now to use that unalocated space. When it promps you how you want to install it you just chose "Install allong side Windows". and you will have windows 8 side by side with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a pre-installed Windows 8 system with UEFI system, definitely yes! I have spent days on this and finally been able to have both of them. If you have a new laptop (as in recently purchased) go for 13.04 64-bit. I had installed 12.04.2 64-bit but it doesnt have some wireless drivers which you have to manually install. 
What I did:

1. Copied the files in the iso (Ubuntu 12.04.2 64-bit) as it is into a pen drive.
2. Disable FastStartup in Windows 8. (Power options in Control Panel, and Changesettings currently unavailable)
   Also, create two partitions (compmgmt.msc or any other wizrd). One small 3-4 gb partition for swap. And the other for installing ubuntu in.
3. Windows + I. Shift+Restart.
4. Troubleshoot-->Advanced Options-->UEFI Firmware settings. Restart.
5. Boot Menu. Disable SecureBoot.
6. Windows will restart. Again do steps 3 and 4.
7. Now choose boot device selection (F9).
8. Select UEFI file. Select the USB. In the USB, go to the EFI folder. Then boot. Then BOOTx64.efi.
9. Install Ubuntu.  MAKE SURE YOU ARE CONNECTED TO THE NET. For the partitions, select the swap partition and one root partition to be formatted into ext4.
10. The bottom option for boot loader also in the partition where you ubuntu root is.
11. Install it. And it will ask you to restart.
12. Restart and lo behold.! You boot directly to Windows.! Damn.!
13. Once again follow steps 3,4 and after tha 7,8. This time select try ubuntu.
14. Run the boot-repair as given in the askubuntu post.

My errors : During the disk management while installing ubuntu I had also selected the efi partition of windows and given it as an efi in the options. DONT DO THIS. This makes the efi unreadable. And gives an error. I had to use System Recovery given by HP.